# Update twice nested repeated record

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm struggling with this query (dummy version, there are much more fields in it) :

```
UPDATE 
  table1 as base
SET 
  lines = 
    ARRAY(
          SELECT AS STRUCT 
            b.line_id,
            s.purch_id,
            ARRAY(
                  SELECT AS STRUCT
                    wh.warehouse_id,
                    s.is_proposed,
                  FROM table1 as t, UNNEST(lines) as lb, UNNEST(lb.warehouses) as wh
                  INNER JOIN 
                    (SELECT 
                      l.line_id,
                      wh.is_proposed
                     FROM table2, UNNEST(lines) as l, UNNEST(l.warehouses) as wh) as s
                  ON lb.line_id = s.line_id AND wh.warehouse_id = s.warehouse_id)
          FROM table1, UNNEST(lines) as b
          INNER JOIN UNNEST(supply.lines) as s
          ON b.line_id = s.line_id)
FROM 
  table2 as supply
WHERE 
  base.date = supply.date
  AND
  base.sales_id = supply.sales_id
```

table1 and table2 have the same nesting :

- `lines` : repeated record
- `lines.warehouses` : repeated record within lines

(so {... , lines [{... warehouses [)

Plus table1 is a subset of table2 with a subset of its fields, table1 having them NULL from start (I refresh information when data is available because informations are asynchroneous).

I first tried this as a first step (which succeeds) :

```
UPDATE 
  table1 as base
SET 
  lines = 
    ARRAY(
          SELECT AS STRUCT 
            b.line_id,
            s.purch_id,
            b.warehouses
          FROM table1, UNNEST(lines) as b
          INNER JOIN UNNEST(supply.lines) as s
          ON b.line_id = s.line_id)
FROM 
  table2 as supply
WHERE 
  base.date = supply.date
  AND
  base.sales_id = supply.sales_id
```

But the fact I actually need to update `lines.warehouses` too so I'm happy it works but it is not enough.

The full query is valid and when I try the last ARRAY part in a terminal, the query is fast and the output has no duplicate.
Still the complete UPDATE does not end (after 20 min, I killed it).

Tables are not that large, 20k from both side (220k completely flattened).

So am I doing something wrong ? 
Is there a better way ?

Thanks

Comment: I believe your ARRAY(...) statement on line 9 is what's causing the issue.  I'm pretty sure it is one of two issues.  Potentially the `select` within the ARRAY() is getting executed once, returns a big result, and is updating that big result to every line in `table1`.  The other possibility is that the `select` within the ARRAY() is getting executed a bunch of times (once for every line in `UNNEST(lines)`).  Neither sounds performant.

Comment: I thought something similar because the query keeps adding output/steps in aggregate (if I understand the job details correctly). Do you know any other pattern to achieve that ? I imagined flattening both tables, then joining, then renesting but it seems impossible to do with UPDATE pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the issue, Iit was way simpler than I thought.
I think I misunderstood how the whole query nesting worked.

So I just linked every data avaiable, from the first singular row matched to the last array since filtered data at top level is propagated to lower levels.

```
UPDATE 
  table1 as base
SET 
  lines = 
    ARRAY(
          SELECT AS STRUCT 
            b.line_id,
            s.purch_id,
            ARRAY(
                  SELECT AS STRUCT
                    wh.warehouse_id,
                    sh.is_proposed,
                  FROM UNNEST(b.warehouses) as wh -- take only upper level data
                  INNER JOIN UNNEST(s.warehouses) as sh -- idem
                  ON wh.warehouse_id = sh.warehouse_id) -- no need to 'redo' the joining on already filtered ones
          FROM UNNEST(base.lines) as b
          INNER JOIN UNNEST(supply.lines) as s
          ON b.line_id = s.line_id)
FROM 
  table2 as supply
WHERE 
  base.date = supply.date
  AND
  base.sales_id = supply.sales_id
```

The query succeeds in less than 1min